# error when calling the distributeMessage method using now.js

Tags: node.js, chat, nowjs-sockets

Started playing with the now.js framework.  Using the example code in now.js I'm trying to implement a chat.  Including here for completeness.

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/nowjs/now.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- HTML for Chat Here  -->

$(document).ready(function() {

  now.receiveMessage = function(name, message) {
    $(".chattext").append("<br>" + name + ": " + message);
    $(".chattext").attr({ scrollTop: $(".chattext").attr("scrollHeight") });
  }

  $("#send-button").click(function() {
    now.distributeMessage($("#text-input").val());
    $("#text-input").val("");
  });

  now.name = prompt("What's your name?", "")

});
```

I've got the node.js server with now.js working properly.

I'm trying to extend the chat so that when a user enters their name, a message is sent to the server noting that " has now joined the chat."  The example code prompts a user for a name and sets that to the now object's name.

```
now.name = prompt("What's your name?", "");
```

At this point, the now object is available.  So instead of simply setting the now.name, I'm trying to set the now.name AND send a message by calling distributeMessage('John has joined chat.')

```
var p = prompt("What's your name?", "");
if (!p) {
    // errs here
} else {
    now.name = p;
    now.distributeMessage(now.name + " has joined chat.");
}
```

Chrome and firefox report an error that reads

**Object #<Object> has no method 'distributeMessage'.**

I don't understand why.  The now.name property can be set.  The console log shows the object with get distributeMessage and set distributeMessage functions.  I can send the message when I click on the 'send-button' element.  But, I am unable to call the distributeMessage at this point.

Is the now object not fully loaded when I try to make the method call?  Do I need to include some sort of 'now' onLoadReady method?  What do I need to do in order to fire off the now.distributeMessage method after the prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a method to address my issue.  I need to surround the call to distribute message with a

```
now.ready(function() {
  now.distributeMessage(now.name + " has joined chat.");
})
```

It seems the client side now namespace was available but all serverside now calls still required javascript to finish processing.

Comment: It is better to update your question rather than answering it by yourself if this still not solving your question.

Comment: Thanks lig, using now.ready does resolve the problem and thus answers my question.  Is there something I can do to make that clearer in my answer?

Comment: I was facing the same problem, and it still doesn't resolve my issue.